# Unable to Add repository in Xcode5

Tags: xcode, svn

I am getting some strange error while adding a repository in Xcode5.

The screen shot is attached.

[image]

However, I am able to access the the same repository through SVNX, terminal and web-browsers.
*No need to say I am using the same credentials.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Make sure that you enter the correct URL.* Paths in Subversion repos are case-sensitive so do access rules. I.e. you may get Access Forbidden error just because the URL is incorrect.
2. *See what's logged to Apache HTTP Server's log when you get the error.* If the above advise does not help and you are sure that other svn clients and web browsers authenticate successfully, then looking at logged error events can be very helpful to determine the root cause.